# How does Hibernate 1st and 2nd Level cache work with multiple sessions

Tags: java, hibernate, session, caching, transactions

I'm new in Hibernate, I know that level1 cache is session-scope and level2 cache is cross-sessions, suppose I have an entity Person which contains fields Id and Name.

1. create session1 and load a person, Id=1, Name="AAA"
2. create session2, update this person,
   session.saveOrUpdate(person), Id=1, Name="BBB"
3. back to session1 and update again, 
   session.saveOrUpdate(person), Id=1, Name="AAA"

---

Below is my guess about what hibernate do internally:

for step 1

hibernate search level1 cache of session1, nothing there

hibernate search level2 cache, nothing there

hibernate search database

entity is stored into level1 and leve2 caches

now both level1 and level2 caches have an entity, person with id=1 and name="AAA"

---

for step 2

hibernate search level1 cache of session2, nothing there

hibernate search level2 cache, get the entity(person with id=1 and name="AAA")

store this entity into level1 cache of session2

compare this entity to the parameter of session.saveOrUpdate(person)

name is changed, so an update is needed

level1 cache of session2 is updated

level2 cache is updated

database is updated

---

for step 3

hibernate search level1 cache of session1, get the entity(person with id=1 and name="AAA")

compare this entity to the parameter of session.saveOrUpdate(person)

nothing changed

so database will not be updated?

---

I'll try to write some test code, but before that, it would be strongly appreciated if someone can point out any misunderstanding above, that would be helpful for me to understand hibernate caches deeper.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most of your assumptions are correct except the following ones:

- **saveOrUpdate** is not used to propagate update changes but to:

  1. persist a transient entity (e.g. save)
  2. reattach a detached entity (e.g. update)

When you load an entity in a Session, it's loaded into 1st level cache and any change you make to the entity will be discovered and propagated during flush time. So you don't have to call saveOrUpdate in this case.

- In your example at step 3), Hibernate doesn't detect any change in your first session so it has nothing to update, even if some other session has already update the entity.

  In order to prevent "lost updates" Hibernates offers:

  1. optimistic locking (@Version)
  2. pessimistic locking (instructing the db to acquire locks)

If you choose optimistic locking, and in step 3. you change the entity name to 'CCC' you will get a org.hibernate.StaleObjectStateException (during flush time), indicating you have a stale version of the entity you try to save.